# C# Web API - Returning response from another API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

A little explanation here. We have a legacy application that needs to interact with a payment `web API` that uses `TLS 1.2`. The application is using `.Net Framework 2.0` which apparently does not support `TLS 1.2`. In order to allow this older application to use the web API, the plan is to create a tiny web API of our own using `ASP.Net` Web API. This new API will be called by the old software and our middle man API will make a request to the payment API and return the response. I want the response from the middle man API to match the response from the payment API exactly. This is the code I've come up with:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/payment")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Payment()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "thing1", "hello" },
           { "thing2", "world" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("url/to/payment/api", content);
        IHttpActionResult response = ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
        return response;
    }
```

My question is will the code below maintain the state of the response from the payment API? We don't want to have to modify the old software in the event the response from our middle man API differs from the payment API response.

Comment: So your API (the code posted) is the "Middleman" API that interfaces to the ``url/to/payment/api`` API? Then you can just return the value that you receive from the ``HttpResponseMessage`` object in your ``Payment()`` API method.

Comment: Yep that is the code for the middle man api. I know I can return just the object, but I also want to maintain the status codes returned from the payment api. The legacy application has code that is run based on the status code of the response. So I would want to keep them the same. I guess that's my biggest concern.

Comment: What I would suggest is testing some basic calls to your middleman API with a web debugger such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and verify that the status codes and return data is correct depending on what kind of responses you were expecting. The code you posted looks fine, but to verify that it's functioning properly, your best bet is to use a web debugger.

Comment: You should match your DTOs with the ones of the Payment API, both requests and responses.

Comment: Yeah def going to check everything out using fiddler and postman. I'm not concerned about Dtos. The payment app returns an xml string that I'm not concerned with. I just want to return the response as is to ensure the response content and status codes are what our legacy software should expect.

Comment: @Singularity222 Hi, I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing, did you find a solution?